# Remove Last Page from the PDF

Tags: visualforce, pdf, css

I have created PDF of Multipage, where in VF page I am using

```
<apex:repeat .......>
 ///////// some code
  <div style="page-break-before:always;"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

But it adds a Blank page in the end each time, how can I avoid that one

I am trying this one, where flag=True in constructor. Note : I do not have any method written in Controller to change flags value.

```
<apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!flag}">
    <div style="page-break-after:always;"/>
    <apex:param assignTo="{!flag}" value="False"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

I thought it will execute only once

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've handled this directly as part of my Apex code by using some CSS tricks. Try this out.

```
<apex:variable var="cnt" value="{!0}" />    
<apex:repeat value="{!cases}" var="cse"> 
      <!-- apex:OutputText value="{!cnt}"/ -->
     <div style="{!if(cnt < 1, 'page-break-before:avoid;','page-break-before:always;')}">
     <apex:variable var="cnt" value="{!cnt+1}"/> .... .... </div> 
 </apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use post-processing tools such as this: [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/commandline/) to strip the last page from a pdf. Perhaps a Heroku Rest service that accepts pdfs and returns the pdf - last page.